# How extract path from string using regex

Tags: java, regex

How do I extract /path/index.html from following string

```
url("/path/index.html")
url(/path/index.html)
```

I using following regex, but don't work.

```
Pattern.compile("\\b(href=|url\\()([\"\'])(([^/]+://)([^/<>]+))?([^\"\'>]*)([\"\']|\\))", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.CANON_EQ);
```

Comment: Use the URL class not regex

Comment: `String res = s.replaceFirst("^url\\(\"?(.*?)\"?\\)$", "$1");`

Comment: Do not use class `URL`, as it can cause network traffic. Use class `URI` instead...

Comment: Looking at your current regex it seems like there may be other formats too. Please update the question with any more examples of strings from which you may want to extract paths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like some people above stated already, it is better to use the built-in URI helper class. However, if you really need to use a regex for that(and the strings you provided are all the available cases), something like this should do it for you:

```
/url\("?(.*?)"?\)/
```

It should look something like this when you pass the pattern as a string in java:

```
"url\\(\"?(.*?)\"?\\)"
```

You can then find the string you're looking for in the matched groups.

Comment: Thanks a lot of  It' s help for me .In fact I had been developing a reverse_httpproxy. I want to extract path and replace the path.

finally I fixed the regex to following

`\\b(href=|href\\s=\\s|src\\s*=\\s*.*host\\s*\\+\\s*|src\\s*=\\s*|action\\s*=\\s*.*host\\s*\\+\\s*|action\\s*=\\s*|url\\s*=\\s*|url\\(\\s*)(\\\\*[\"']|(?<=url\\())(([^/]+://)([^/<>]+))?([^\"'>\\)]*)(\\)|[\"']`

Answer (score 0):

This will satisfy your requirement.

```
 String url = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45545336/how-extract-path-from-string-using-regex";
 String[] pieces = url.replaceFirst("://", "/").split("/");
```

Comment: Thank for replied .  I just want extract whole path like 

input : url("/path/index.html")
match : /path/index.html

input : url(/path/index.html)
match :/path/index.html